# Difference in QByteArray.data() and constData()

Tags: qt, qt5, qbytearray

With Qt 5.8.0.

This code runs as I expected.

```
static const char mydata[] = {
   0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4
};

QByteArray ba  = QByteArray::fromRawData(mydata, sizeof(mydata));

const char *p  = ba.constData();
const char *pp = QByteArray::fromRawData(mydata, sizeof(mydata)).constData();

qDebug("%p %p\n", p, pp);
```

**output**

```
0x40f548 0x40f548
```

**dump**

```
p  0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04  
pp 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
```

But, I am struggling to understand what happens with this code after using *data()* instead of *constData()*.

```
char *p = ba.data();
char *pp = QByteArray::fromRawData(mydata, sizeof(mydata)).data();
```

**output**

```
0x166941e8 0x166f8e70
```

**dump**

```
p  0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04  
pp 0xee 0xfe 0xee 0xfe 0xee 0xfe ... (should be 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 ?)
```

Comment: The docs explain [constData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#constData), and [QByteArray::fromRawData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromRawData)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Qt documentation, `data()` function gives you a deep copy of pointer to QByteArray data so every time that is called, it will gives you another value (different address).

While `constData()` gives you a read only pointer to main object so it value doesn't change on every time calling.

For more details you can check [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data) for data() function description, and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#constData) for constData() description.

Comment: with data(), I think it's still implicit-shared, so 'p' equals 'pp'. And why does not 'pp' have mydata of 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ?

Comment: If you use data() for p and pp at the same time, result would be the same (memory address). but if you use data() for p or pp and constData() for the other you will receive different memory address. 
If you want to access your data you can use p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] or pp[0], pp[1], pp[2], pp[3] with data() or constData() you can access to your data there is no difference. but you need to cast it to int or QChar to see it. int(p[0])